# SVG nine-slice scaling

Tags: svg

How could one obtain [nine-slice scaling](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2007/04/understanding-9-slice-scaling.html) in SVG?
Specifically, I'm looking for a way to define SVG objects that behave like nine-sliced objects when resized (some elements maintain their dimension, and others scale with the container).

Comment: Based on my own related question, I am beginning to think this is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763823/possible-to-build-an-svg-that-has-fluid-horizontal-scaling-similar-to-old-table

Comment: It's possible, see dirk's solution below.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant to apply it to an svg, then the [CSS3 Borders and backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) spec should help you do that if you reference an svg.

If you meant you wanted to do it inside an svg file, then you might be able to use a [<pattern>](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#Patterns) (possibly combined with some nested <svg> elements) to do something similar. Nested <svg> elements might be another way to do this, see e.g [this example](http://treebuilder.de/svg/svgincss/tv/test3.html). Alternatively use 9 <use> elements with different transforms, each having a different clip-path applied.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but that example achieves its "Scalability" by using a rectangle with a border radius, and not by using a pattern, nested svg or use element.

Comment: The example uses this svg as a css background image: http://treebuilder.de/svg/svgincss/tv/tv.svg. That svg has another <svg> nested inside.

Comment: But the nested svg just draws the 'base' of the tv - you can delete it and the tv still exhibits "nine-slice" like scaling.It is the corners of the tv that are of interest and those only scale properly because they are using a rectangle with border radius instead of a path...

Answer (score 4):

You need something like a margin around the elements that form the edges and the center, to tell them to start X pixels from the left/top to y pixels from the right/bottom. Use a foreignObject, like this:

```
<foreignObject width="100%" height="100px">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin: 0 100px;">
        <svg>
            <!-- code here -->
        </svg>
    </div>
</foreignObject>
```

I wrote about methods of applying scaling grids to SVG here: http://w3.eleqtriq.com/2014/03/the-holy-grail-of-image-scaling/
Cheers, Dirk

Comment: This is excellent work. I just posted a feature request at Adobe asking them to look at your implementation. Maybe they can add it to SVG export. Maybe we can all go in and vote for it...
https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/37263052-support-for-9-slice-scaling-in-svg