# Is there a way to apply 9-patch / scale-9 principles in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm wondering if there is a way to make an svg graphic that would scale accordingly to the same principle as [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) on Android (or like scale 9 in flash).

Basically, part of the content inside the svg should scale accordingly to the normal expansion rules of the viewport but certain elements would remain unscaled and anchored as defined in the svg file.

(The idea would be to make some complicated background for some buttons using SVG but allowing them to scale accordingly with the inner content of the button)

I don't think it's possible with plain svg declarations, but maybe with a bit of embedded scripting, though I couldn't find any example or library doing this..

**Edit: ** I'm aware of [this year old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547993/svg-nine-slice-scaling) but I'm hoping someone may have an alternative, more reusable option / library

Comment: I too am hoping to find a proper solution to this, is there really no  solution out there?

Comment: I have recently made another post along the same lines. I do not think this is possible with a single self-contained svg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763823/possible-to-build-an-svg-that-has-fluid-horizontal-scaling-similar-to-old-table

Comment: I stand corrected, see dirk's solution below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote about it on my blog, it's possible in a "perfect" way when you are willing to sacrifice IE and an "almost" way that works in IE as well as long as you can live with a not so perfect solution: http://w3.eleqtriq.com/2014/03/the-holy-grail-of-image-scaling/