# Possible to build an svg that has fluid horizontal scaling, similar to old table-slice method?

Tags: css, svg

I am attempting to build an svg that can be scaled horizontally and fluidly, similar to the old table-sliced images used to scale a header fluidly across the top of a page. Typically this requires the end component(s) not to stretch while the center component does stretch (or repeat). I have included an example image below. I have experimented with nested svg tags combined with viewBox and preserveAspectRatio in a variety of configurations but can't quite get it to work.

[image: Fuild Horizontal Scaling Diagram]

Here is a working example of what I need to do, in pure html/css: http://plnkr.co/edit/cSHBV27fL6k2m67FgwlA?p=preview

Is it even possible to do this with a single self-contained svg, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: If this is in a website, you could use javascript.

Comment: It is in a website, but I'm likely to have a lot of these being positioned on the screen dynamically all with varying widths. The ideal/elegant/performant solution imo would be to re-use a single svg and use javascript to dynamically set the width of each instance differently, while internally the svg components take care of themselves.

Comment: Found two other related posts. Based on the lack of answers for these, I do not think this is possible to do with a single self-contained svg.
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547993/svg-nine-slice-scaling
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061205/is-there-a-way-to-apply-9-patch-scale-9-principles-in-svg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm answering this because I had to do the something similar.

**Yes**, you can do it with just **SVG**.  The key attributes are `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`.  `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid"` keeps the rectangle to the right and `xMinYMid` keeps the rectangle to the left.  Set the `viewBox` to be the desired size of the rectangles on the end.

This has been tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Here is a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lAjF2gTb5tYvz2lwstCR?p=preview).

Note that if the change the height of the svg to 100% instead of 20px you can make the image scale with a containing html `div`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="100%" height="20px" version="1.0" state='normal'
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">


    <defs>

        <!-- The right head --> 
        <svg class='head input-source' id='right' 
            height="100%"
            width='100%' 
            viewBox="0 0 15 30"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid"
            >
            <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </svg>

        <!-- The left head --> 
        <svg class='head input-source' id='left' 
            height="100%"
            width='100%' 
            viewBox="0 0 15 30"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid"
            >
            <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </svg>

    </defs>

    <svg
        class='input-source'
        stroke='black'
        stroke-width='0'
        fill="green">
        <rect  x="2" y="20%" width="100%" height="60%" 
            stroke='black'
            stroke-width='0'
        >
        </rect>
        <use xlink:href='#right'/>
        <use xlink:href='#left'/>
    </svg>   
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice job with this... I'm not sure if this was possible 4 years ago but it seems to work perfectly now so I'm updating the answer as this is definitely the best implementation I've seen.

Comment: I remember finding your question about two years ago and I finally got back to working on my stuff.  I was very close two years ago and now I finally figured it out.  What you and I were trying to do was definitely not covered in any of the how to's I found.  Thanks for the original question because it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible without Javascript by using foreignObject. But it will not work in Internet Explorer, bcs. IE doesn't support foreignObject. See my article at http://w3.eleqtriq.com/2014/03/the-holy-grail-of-image-scaling/

Comment: Wow, that's some great work you've done on solving this issue, thanks for posting it. In my particular case I don't care about IE. Complicated, but it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you can place each svg in a DIV, its size will determine its svg. However, svg sizing must be in percentages. This may not serve you, for complex svg, with everything is 'floating'

The simple rectangle example is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
DIV width=400px height=100px:
<div  style='width:400px;height:100px;'>
<svg id="mySVG1" width="100%" height="100%">
<rect x=0 y=0 width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue' stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="20%" y="20%" width="60%" height="60%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="80%" y="0%" width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
</div>
<br />No DIV<br />
<svg id="mySVG2" width="100%" height="100%" >
<rect x=0 y=0 width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue' stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="20%" y="20%" width="60%" height="60%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="80%" y="0%" width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
<br />DIV width=300px height=50px:
<div  style='width:300px;height:50px;'>
<svg id="mySVG2" width="100%" height="100%" >
<rect x=0 y=0 width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue' stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="20%" y="20%" width="60%" height="60%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
<rect x="80%" y="0%" width="20%" height="100%" fill='lightBlue'  stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
</div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a good idea but unfortunately in practice it does not work. Check out this plunkr I just created from your code to see it run. Aspect ratios of the end blocks inside each of the svgs are still being scaled to a percentage of the viewbox's width, rather than remaining at a fixed width. http://plnkr.co/edit/A7kpBiAmKDqVzTKYdBfr?p=preview

Comment: This can be done with 3 polygons that are written after the HTML  is loaded, to reflect the width settings of the various svg blocks. Would you want to go there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Also, I added a plunkr example a pure html/css implementation of this to my original post, to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish with a single self-contained svg.

Comment: I assumed you didn't want a javascript method. since this was under CSS tag. Be happy to do it with javascript...;)

Comment: Yes, the end blocks are changing.  Check out my answer below for a SVG only answer that doesn't distort the end blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript means to adjust the rectangles based on svg width. Sorry I couldn't create a CSS approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<svg  width="200" height="40">
<rect id="leftAnchoRect" x="0" y="0" fill=blue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" width="40" height="40" />
<rect id="centerExpandRect" fill=lightBlue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" x=40  y=10  height="20" />
<rect id="floatRightRect" fill=red stroke='black' stroke-width="1" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
</svg>
<br />
<svg  width="250" height="40">
<rect id="leftAnchoRect" x="0" y="0" fill=blue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" width="40" height="40" />
<rect id="centerExpandRect" fill=lightBlue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" x=40  y=10  height="20" />
<rect id="floatRightRect" fill=red stroke='black' stroke-width="1" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
</svg>
<br />
<svg  width="300" height="40">
<rect id="leftAnchoRect" x="0" y="0" fill=blue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" width="40" height="40" />
<rect id="centerExpandRect" fill=lightBlue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" x=40  y=10  height="20" />
<rect id="floatRightRect" fill=red stroke='black' stroke-width="1" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
</svg>
<br />
<svg  width="500" height="40">
<rect id="leftAnchoRect" x="0" y="0" fill=blue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" width="40" height="40" />
<rect id="centerExpandRect" fill=lightBlue stroke='black' stroke-width="1" x=40  y=10  height="20" />
<rect id="floatRightRect" fill=red stroke='black' stroke-width="1" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
</svg>
<br />
</center>
<script id=myScript>
document.addEventListener("onload",adjustRects(),false)
function adjustRects()
{
    var svgElems=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")
    for(var k=0;k<svgElems.length;k++)
    {
        var svg=svgElems[k]
        var rects=svg.getElementsByTagName("rect")
        var midRect=rects[1]
        var rightRect=rects[2]

        var svgWidth=parseInt(svg.getAttribute("width"))
        var midWidth=svgWidth-80
        var floatX=svgWidth-40
        midRect.setAttribute("width",midWidth)
        rightRect.setAttribute("x",floatX)
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```